# Relacionar tablas Comunidades Provincias SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una **base de datos `SQL`** **en `MySQL`** de comunidades, con sus respectivas provincias.

He añadido mi **unión de ambas tablas**. Por ejemplo, para saber que Sevilla y Córboba pertenecen a Andalucía.

**¿Es correcta mi respuesta?**

**Código:**

```
use spain;

CREATE TABLE comunidades (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    comunidad varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
    capital_id int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO comunidades (id, comunidad, capital_id) VALUES 
(1, "Andalucia", 6152),
(2, "Aragon", 8113),
(3, "Principado de Asturias", 5009),
(4, "Islas Baleares", 836),
(5, "Canarias", 5252),
(6, "Cantabria", 5823),
(7, "Castilla y Leon", 7415),
(8, "Castilla - La Mancha", 6934),
(9, "Cataluña", 881),
(10, "Comunitad Valenciana", 7219),
(11, "Extremadura", 712),
(12, "Galicia", 2198),
(13, "Comunidad de Madrid ", 4356),
(14, "Region de Murcia", 4588),
(15, "Comunidad Foral de Navarra", 4815),
(16, "Pais Vasco", 46),
(17, "La Rioja", 4124),
(18, "Ceuta", 8115),
(19, "Melilla", 8116);


CREATE TABLE provincias (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    provincia varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
    comunidad_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    capital_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT "-1"
    FOREIGN KEY (comunidad_id) REFERENCES comunidades(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO provincias (id, provincia, comunidad_id, capital_id) VALUES
(1, "Álava", 16, 46),
(2, "Albacete", 8, 54),
(3, "Alicante", 10, 152),
(4, "Almería", 1, 292),
(5, "Ávila", 7, 395),
(6, "Badajoz", 11, 644),
(7, "Illes Balears", 4, 836),
(8, "Barcelona", 9, 881),
(9, "Burgos", 7, 1220),
(10, "Cáceres", 11, 1580),
(11, "Cádiz", 1, 1776),
(12, "Castellón", 10, 1844),
(13, "Ciudad Real", 8, 1978),
(14, "Córdoba", 1, 2065),
(15, "A Coruña", 12, 2150),
(16, "Cuenca", 8, 2285),
(17, "Girona", 9, 2526),
(18, "Granada", 1, 2747),
(19, "Guadalajara", 8, 2947),
(20, "Guipúzcoa", 16, 3159),
(21, "Huelva", 1, 3257),
(22, "Huesca", 2, 3396),
(23, "Jaén", 1, 3545),
(24, "León", 7, 3676),
(25, "Lleida", 9, 3918),
(26, "La Rioja", 17, 4124),
(27, "Lugo", 12, 4238),
(28, "Madrid", 13, 4356),
(29, "Málaga", 1, 4523),
(30, "Murcia", 14, 4588),
(31, "Navarra", 15, 4815),
(32, "Ourense", 12, 4925),
(33, "Asturias", 3, 5009),
(34, "Palencia", 7, 5137),
(35, "Las Palmas", 5, 5252),
(36, "Pontevedra", 12, 5312),
(37, "Salamanca", 7, 5588),
(38, "Santa Cruz de Tenerife", 5, 5732),
(39, "Cantabria", 6, 5823),
(40, "Segovia", 7, 6024),
(41, "Sevilla", 1, 6152),
(42, "Soria", 7, 6307),
(43, "Tarragona", 9, 6499),
(44, "Teruel", 2, 6721),
(45, "Toledo", 8, 6934),
(46, "Valencia", 10, 7219),
(47, "Valladolid", 7, 7415),
(48, "Vizcaya", 16, 7489),
(49, "Zamora", 7, 7821),
(50, "Zaragoza", 2, 8113),
(51, "Ceuta", 18, 8115),
(52, "Melilla", 19, 8116);
```

Comment: Lo que buscas es unir ambas tablas no?

Comment: Sí, había pensado en: FOREIGN KEY (capital_id) REFERENCES comunidades(id) ON DELETE CASCADE pero no sé si es correcto o no, por eso conseguir la mejor respuesta.

Comment: Lo puedes hacer de ambas formas, pero para este tipo de tablas con registros que son casi como constantes, lo lógico es que la relación entre ellas sea simplemente una `foreing key`

Comment: @RogerTorné Había pensado en realizarlo con: FOREIGN KEY (capital_id) REFERENCES comunidades(id) ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: @BetaM Edité la pregunta para que se vea más clara y concisa. ¿Es correcta mi unión o es poco segura?

Comment: @BetaM ¿Dónde se mira? ¿En select table_schema,table_name,engine from information_schema.tables;? ENGINE=MyISAM

Comment: Es decir si usas MySQL, SQL server, Oracle o asi

Comment: @BetaM Perfecto, lo añado.

Answer (score 3):

Podemos mencionar que:

Las *foreign keys* te ayudarán a vincular 2 o mas tablas por medio de sus llaves primarias y foráneas.

Luego cuando sucedan acciones como:

- `DELETE`
- `UPDATE`

A los registros de la tabla padre, deberás determinar que es lo que les va a ocurrir a los registros relacionados en la o las otras tablas vinculadas; teniendo opciones como:

- `CASCADE`
- `SET NULL`
- `NO ACTION`
- `RESTRICT`

Ahora cuando estás construyendo el *CONSTRAINT* que te permita la vinculación entre tablas deberías tener una sintaxis similar a la siguiente:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_tabla2_tabla1 FOREIGN KEY(llave_foranea) REFERENCES tabla1(llave_primaria) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Para el ejemplo anterior le indico que cuando un registro de la tabla padre sea eliminado, en consencuencia eso ocurrirá con todos los registros asociados en la tabla hija(tabla 2).

Luego entonces si debes colocar un: no action, delete, null dependerá de ¿qué es lo que quieres preservar o no de esos registros relacionados?

Al menos para el caso de MySQL Server y MariaDB Server (desconozco en cualquier otro), el no declarar una acción clara para los registros vinculados en la acción que tiene *por default* y sería equivalente a un `RESTRICT`

**Fuente de consulta**

- [Acciones referenciales](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Gracias por explicación entendí lo de las tablas. Es decir, si elimino Andalucia, quiero borrar Jaén, Córdoba, Sevilla, automáticamente sí. Que el DELETE sea en cascade y se borren automáticamente. Eso quiero preservar. ¿Entonces? ¿Mi respuesta es correcta?

Comment: Si dejamos el uso de CASCADE si provocará que la eliminación de un registro en la tabla A provoqué la eliminación de las filas que tengan un valor coincidente en la tabla B

Comment: +1 respuesta bastante util.